# How can I rename an album using Facebook API?

Tags: facebook

As simple as the title: How can I rename an album using Facebook API?

Comment: And an answer as simple as the Question: Not At All.

Comment: Did you find an answer to that, or an alternative? I tried to call the php page via AJAX in the "same" way (I tried to use the same parameters) facebook does when you click the standard desktop version of facebook (you can monitor what happens by using Firebug, and see exactly what data is sent to facebook when you click what) but it didn't work. Facebook provides way to crete, delete... but not to rename... how stupid is that? Maybe we should start a petition asking facebook to provides this method?

Comment: @firepol AFAIK you cannot delete either....